# full qualified path on Android

Tags: android, resources

How do I get the full qualified path (eg. /res/value-de-land-car-xhdpi-finger-v17...) in Android? I want to test this on three devices and I don't know where to start.

Edit: I want to know the folder while design-time, because I have to know in which folder I have to put my files.

Comment: Seems you want to access the resources. Why can't you use the resource system for that?

Answer (score 1):

It is not possible to get the path of the resource folder. The resource folder is compiled into the apk, and it may not even store as it is. (e.g. those layout xml files are no longer xml files once it is compiled).

I dont know what you are trying to achieve here, but one solution could be to push the file you need to a known location(like /mnt/sdcard/... ) with sdk-tools.

Answer (score 0):

Use the [getAbsolutePath()](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/io/File.html#getAbsoluteFile%28%29) method from a File object.

Create the File object with the File("relative/path/to/file") constructor.

Edit: Now that I noticed your example. If what you really want to do is get the absolute path of a resource, it's not possible as far as I know and you probably shouldn't want to do that either. You shouldn't rely on how Android packages your application, it could change in the future.

Comment: Okay, I write it unclear. I want to know, which file will be found in my project. I want to write a game and have all three current Nexus devices, but now I don't know, which assets each device will choose.

Comment: It seems what you need is to better understand resources (http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/providing-resources.html). For example, for the resource layout: a diferent layout will be applied depending on the pixel density of the device. It could be layout-mdpi, layout-hdpi, layout-xhdpi, etc. The same happens with other resources. Try to expand the question if it's still not clear please.

Comment: That is clear and I know the folder. But, I want on all Nexus devices (Nexus 4, Nexus 7, Nexus 10) a font size, that will be exactly the same space (in relation) to the screensize for every device. I tested it with eg. 10dp (now, every text is in reality exact size, but not in relation to the screen).
If you want, I can post some screenshots ;)

Comment: That's weird. That's exactly what density pixels are for.

Comment: Eg. my screen is 10cm width and my font should have a width 5cm. How do I archive, that on a 20cm screen my font is 10cm width? That's what I want. Can I just calc screen.getWidth() / 2?